# concatenating column value from multiple rows based on ordering sequence logic in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

On SQL server 2008 I have following results

```
id  combo                  name   value
-----------------------------------------
1   var1 + var2            var1   123
1   var1 + var2            var2   456
2   var1 + var4 + var2     var1   789
2   var1 + var4 + var2     var2   432
2   var1 + var4 + var2     var4   600
3   var1 + var2 + var3     var1   654
3   var1 + var2 + var3     var2   987
3   var1 + var2 + var3     var3   654
```

I need to flat the list so the instead of combo I'll get values for that combo.

```
id     values   
-----------------------------------------
1      123.456
2      789.600.432
3      654.987.654
```

Edit: Please check the **combo** column. That is the key column how value should be merged. So second item is 789.600.432 and not 789.432.600

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: No more a duplicate question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string does not addres ordering logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below query. It has been updated based on your question.

```
select distinct id,
stuff(
            (
                Select 
                     '.'+t1.[value]
                from tbl t1 
                    where t1.ID=t2.ID 
                    order by CHARINDEX(t1.name,t1.combo)
                for xml path('') 
            ),1,1,'') 
            as [values]
from tbl t2
```

**Demo** sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba4a1/12

**Explanation:** The query uses `FOR XML PATH` in outer query to get concatenated values per id row in correct order using position of name in combo string.